# conda - PATH order in fish shell

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, fish

I'm using miniconda on Ubuntu 20.04 with fish shell. I was able to create and activate my specific environment. My problem is with Python version which is related with `$PATH`.

1. When I start clean fish shell, conda set it up for (base) environment `$PATH` looks like this:

`PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/conda/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/conda/bin`

it means, when I start Python it uses `/opt/conda/bin/python` version - conda (base) version.

2. When I start my environment `conda activate XXX` it switch to XXX (more precisely, switch from base to XXX) and my `$PATH` looks like this:

`PATH=/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/USER/.conda/envs/XXX/bin:/snap/bin:/opt/conda/bin`

it means, when I start Python it uses `/usr/bin/python`. It is system version of Python.

3. When I start new fish shell, deactivate (base) environment and and activate created one (XXX), `$PATH` looks like:

`PATH=/home/USER/.conda/envs/XXX/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/conda/bin`

it means, when I start Python it uses `/home/USER/.conda/envs/XXX/bin/python`

Problems:

- Whenever I use XXX environment I expect to use `/home/USER/.conda/envs/XXX/bin/python` which is not true when I switch from (base) to (XXX). To use above python I need to deactivate base and then switch to (XXX). It seams, `/home/USER/...` should always be at the beginning of $PATH to choose appropriate python version.
- I would like to not use (base) as a default when I start new shell. I'v tried `config --set auto_activate_base false` which add `auto_activate_base: false`  to `./condarc` but it seams to be ignored.

My conda version is 4.8.3. My `~/.config/fish/config.fish` contains: `eval /opt/conda/bin/conda "shell.fish" "hook" $argv | source`.

What I'm do wrong? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in one Line and don't bother yourself (MacOS and Linux)

`/(your conda installation path)/bin/conda init fish`

your condo installation usually in '/Users/- your UserName -/anaconda3'

if someone want to know about install fish, best way is Homebrew. after `brew install fish` you must add fish to supportable shells in `/etc/shells`. and then with chsh change default shell to fish.
if it's not clear ask in comment!